# Testing for exception fails

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-testing

When I save a User model, I would like to check if it has a username.
Therefore I wrote this `pre_save`:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def validate_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if len(instance.username) <= 5: raise Exception("Username too short")
```

Now in my testing method I would like to test this exception:

```
def test_user_no_username(self):
    u = User.objects.create()
    self.assertRaises(Exception, u.save())
```

The test fails. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) is kind of a specific exception - *as a second argument you should pass a callable*:

> `assertRaises(exception, callable, *args, **kwds)`

In other words, don't call `u.save()`:

```
self.assertRaises(Exception, u.save)
```

Also, you should really think about having custom exceptions or using built-in Django validation errors instead of raising and catching the broad `Exception`.

Comment: I would add that since we don't know where the test fails, I would think it's failing because of the exception it would raise in the test before `assertRaises` tried to catch it in the `save` call. User.objects.create() will save the instance to the database, trigger the signal and throw the exception, but without catching it for the test's purposes. If you want to instantiate the object before saving it and throwing the (expected) error, use `u = User()`, and then try to catch it with assertRaises as @alecxe says.

Comment: @Saphire ok, how does it fail? Thanks.